# p5js full window camera capture

Tags: javascript, processing, video-capture, video-processing, p5.js

I have a project made in P5.js which I wanted to show online. It's almost done but I want it be fullscreen camera capture with no black background. Just pixels like on the picture. How?

here's the code http://alpha.editor.p5js.org/mvrlena/sketches/r1-IALkPM

[image]

Comment: Which part of this is giving you trouble? Can you please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @KevinWorkman http://alpha.editor.p5js.org/mvrlena/sketches/HyNVlxhGm this part is problematic. When I change the size it does get bigger, but the amount of pixels is the same so the pixels are on a black background

Comment: Then please try to narrow your problem down to a [mcve]. You could start with a much simpler program that just draws a rectangle to the screen, and try to get it working when you resize the window. That will be much easier for us to help with than your whole program.

Answer (score 1):

Questions like this are best answered by looking in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/). It sounds like you're looking for the `windowResized()` and `resizeCanvas()` functions.

The [reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/windowResized) provides some example code:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 100, 200);
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

Try to get something like this simple example working, and then try to work it into your main sketch. If you're still having trouble, please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your whole program. Good luck.